# How to mask weights in PyTorch weight parameters?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I am attempting to mask (force to zero) specific weight values in PyTorch. The weights I am trying to mask are defined as so in the `def __init__`

```
class LSTM_MASK(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, options, inp_dim):
            super(LSTM_MASK, self).__init__()
            ....
            self.wfx = nn.Linear(input_dim, curernt_output, bias=add_bias)
```

The mask is also defined in `def __init__` as

```
self.mask_use = torch.Tensor(curernt_output, input_dim)
```

The mask is a constant and the `.requires_grad_()` is `False` for the mask parameter. Now in the `def forward` part of the class I attempt to do an element-wise multiplication of the weight parameter and the mask before the linear operation is completed

```
def forward(self, x):
    ....
    self.wfx.weight = self.wfx.weight * self.mask_use
    wfx_out = self.wfx(x)
```

I get ann error message:

```
self.wfx.weight = self.wfx.weight * self.mask_use
  File "/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 537, in __setattr__
    .format(torch.typename(value), name))
TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' as parameter 'weight' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)
```

But when I check on the both parameters with `.type()` both of them come up as `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`. I am not sure why there is an error here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The element-wise operation always returns a `FloatTensor`. It is not possible to assign normal tensors as `weight` of layers.

There are two possible options to deal with it. You can assign it to the `data` attribute of your weight, there it is possible assign normal tensors.

Or alternatively you convert your result to an `nn.Parameter` itself, then you can assign it to `wfx.weight`.

Here is an example which shows both ways:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

wfx = nn.Linear(10, 10)
mask_use = torch.rand(10, 10)
#wfx.weight = wfx.weight * mask_use #your example - this raises an error

# Option 1: write directly to data
wfx.weight.data = wfx.weight * mask_use

# Option 2: convert result to nn.Parameter and write to weight
wfx.weight = nn.Parameter(wfx.weight * mask_use)
```

*Disclaimer: When using an `=` (assignment) on the weights you are replacing the weights tensor of your parameter. This may have unwanted effects on the graph resp. the optimization step.*

Comment: Thank you @blue-phoenox, also will switching it out to `self.wfx.weight.data.mul_(self.mask_use)` circumvent the issues that might arise by using an `=`

Comment: @DeepakKadetotad Yes this is much better, actually I just on my way proposing such an operation instead. This way is much better than replacing the weights. But I'm still a bit skeptic that operations like this on the weights during training will result in a smooth conversion, but I haven't tried yet :)

Answer (score 0):

One effective way change your Tensorfloat variable to parameter variable:

```
self.wfx.weight = torch.nn.parameter.Parameter((self.wfx.weight.data * self.mask_use))
```

I hope this would be usefull.